Updating frontend for long running requests/commands - knowing when to refresh UI after an asynchronous read model update
As title says, I have a request (command) which may kick off a series of steps but we can't (or don't want to) keep the web request open. Specifically, if the command causes a change which then updates a read view using eventual consistency (think CQRS with physically separate read and write models), how does the frontend know when to it query the backend for this new data?
Imagine the flow where onboarding a new user creates an event NewUserOnboardedEvent which then causes read model updates  asynchronously:
OnboardNewUserCommand -> NewUserOnboardedEvent -> (UserReadModel.NewUserOnboardedHandler, UpdatedNewUsersThisMonthReadModel.NewUserOnboardedHandler)
Right now, the BE returns after processing OnboardNewUserCommand and the FE just waits 200ms and assumes the read model changes to UserReadModel (and UpdatedNewUsersThisMonthReadModel) will be done, but that's a  sloppy solution and is beginning to fail us when we have lots of traffic.
I'm not quite sure of the nomenclature to use here. Out of band request?
I want to keep my use-case small* - I just need a way for the FE to know when a request (that the FE created) has either finished updating a read model (sometimes there could be multiple read models).
I can see a few ways:

have the request/command return an id, which the frontend can poll
for (naive, and BE will have to persist id with status)
have the request/command return an id which the frontend can establish a
websocket connection or use server sent event** to either:

send the id when the request is done (or there is new data available)

in this situation, the FE can then (re)query the read model


send the id with data updates

establish a websocket or use server sent event of data (or data diff)





I'm leaning towards approach 2.1 as the back end doesn't have to persist the id centrally (like a job queue). Instead it can just keep the ID within the context of the command's flow/downstream events and then create a server sent event when a/the read model has been updated asynchronously. As the FE created the request, when it gets a server side event with the id it would know what part(s) of the view need updating
I'm confident I can make "something work", I'm asking as I want to avoid as much pain and unnecessary "re-inventing the wheel" as possible. If there are some "gotchas" or design concerns I should really consider please do let me know.
I am unfamiliar with all the unhappy paths (refresh FE before command complete, id from command comes back too slow, connection lost, what else?), but as long as a refresh can fix it, there is an escape hatch.
node.js + TS BE, react + TS FE
Thank you
[*] I am not trying go all the way and build a full saga/workflow/activity setup.
[**] I've heard of "Server-Sent Events" but not used them. And I haven't done much web socket work either. I don't want to do loads of plumbing or re-invent a bunch of infrastructure. Trying to keep this vanilla as possible.
